# Text overflow animation

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I accomplish this kind of text animation with flutter when text is longer than it's container?

[image: text oveeflow animation example]

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may try [this](https://pub.dev/packages/marquee) package.

Example:

```
  Marquee(
  text: 'Some sample text that takes some space.',
  style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
  scrollAxis: Axis.horizontal,
  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
  blankSpace: 20.0,
  velocity: 100.0,
  pauseAfterRound: Duration(seconds: 1),
  startPadding: 10.0,
  accelerationDuration: Duration(seconds: 1),
  accelerationCurve: Curves.linear,
  decelerationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
  decelerationCurve: Curves.easeOut,
)
```

Comment: It animates even if the text fits in the available area. I am unable to find a solution where the text animates only if it couldn't fit in the available area.

Answer (score 0):

Try this package: https://pub.dev/packages/overflow_text_animated

```
OverflowTextAnimated(
    text: overflowText,
    style: descriptionStyle,
    animation: OverFlowTextAnimations.infiniteLoop,
    loopSpace: 30,
)
```

Answer (score -1):

```
AutoSizeText(

        text,

        minFontSize: fontSize,

        maxFontSize: fontSize,

        style: TextStyle(

          fontSize: fontSize,

          fontWeight:fontWeight,

        ),

        overflowReplacement: Marquee(

          text: text,

          blankSpace: blankSpace,

          accelerationCurve: Curves.easeOutCubic,

          velocity: velocity,

          startPadding: 2.0,

          startAfter: startAfter,

          pauseAfterRound: pauseAfterRound,

          style: TextStyle(

            fontSize: fontSize,

            fontWeight: fontWeight,

          ),

        ),

  ),
```